# Como obtener data del mercado argentino con quandl para Python

Tags: python, base-de-datos, google-api, data

les muestro mi codigo con el cual estoy tratando de descargar la data el merval. Voy a usar de muestra como bajo la data de AAPL que es todo un exito. pero cuando intento la derl merval me da error. Podrian ayudarme con el codigo correcto porfavor?

```
import quandl 
aapl = quandl.get("WIKI/AAPL", start_date="2000-01-01", end_date="2018-01-01")
print (aapl)

             Open      High       Low    Close      Volume  Ex-Dividend  \
Date                                                                       
2000-01-03  104.87  112.5000  101.6900  111.940   4783900.0          0.0   
2000-01-04  108.25  110.6200  101.1900  102.500   4574800.0          0.0   
2000-01-05  103.75  110.5600  103.0000  104.000   6949300.0          0.0   
2000-01-06  106.12  107.0000   95.0000   95.000   6856900.0          0.0   
2000-01-07   96.50  101.0000   95.5000   99.500   4113700.0          0.0   
2000-01-10  102.00  102.2500   94.7500   97.750   4509500.0          0.0   
2000-01-11   95.94   99.3700   90.5000   92.750   3

Merval = quandl.get("WIKI/MERVAL", start_date="2000-01-01", end_date="2018-01-01")

NotFoundError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-f89b41989853> in <module>()
----> 1 Merval = quandl.get("WIKI/MERVAL", start_date="2000-01-01", end_date="2018-01-01")

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\quandl\get.py in get(dataset, **kwargs)
     46         if dataset_args['column_index'] is not None:
     47             kwargs.update({'column_index': dataset_args['column_index']})
---> 48         data = Dataset(dataset_args['code']).data(params=kwargs, handle_column_not_found=True)
     49     # Array
     50     elif isinstance(dataset, list):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\quandl\model\dataset.py in data(self, **options)
     45         updated_options = Util.merge_options('params', params, **options)
     46         try:
---> 47             return Data.all(**updated_options)
     48         except NotFoundError:
     49             if handle_not_found_error:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\quandl\operations\list.py in all(cls, **options)
     12             options['params'] = {}
     13         path = Util.constructed_path(cls.list_path(), options['params'])
---> 14         r = Connection.request('get', path, **options)
     15         response_data = r.json()
     16         Util.convert_to_dates(response_data)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\quandl\connection.py in request(cls, http_verb, url, **options)
     34         abs_url = '%s/%s' % (ApiConfig.api_base, url)
     35 
---> 36         return cls.execute_request(http_verb, abs_url, **options)
     37 
     38     @classmethod

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\quandl\connection.py in execute_request(cls, http_verb, url, **options)
     42             response = func(url, **options)
     43             if response.status_code < 200 or response.status_code >= 300:
---> 44                 cls.handle_api_error(response)
     45             else:
     46                 return response

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\quandl\connection.py in handle_api_error(cls, resp)
     83         klass = d_klass.get(code_letter, QuandlError)
     84 
---> 85         raise klass(message, resp.status_code, resp.text, resp.headers, code)

NotFoundError: (Status 404) (Quandl Error QECx02) You have submitted an incorrect Quandl code. Please check your Quandl codes and try again.
```

Comment: El error es bastante claro `You have submitted an incorrect Quandl code`, ¿Quandl tiene datos del MERVAL?

Comment: Como se si los tiene?

Comment: Yo consultaría  la documentación en la página de quantl.

Comment: Lo hice, pero no consigo la manera de que me de mas informacion de como bajar data del mercado argentino

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que QUANDL no tiene datos del mercado argentino, de hecho la distribucion de los datos del mercado argentino los maneja BYMA que cobra mas de 10 veces mas caro el acceso a datos que el promedio mundial, una pena

Si es para fines de backtesting de alguna estrategia, podrias usar el ETF que replica el movimiento del merval que es cuyo ticker en NYSE es ARGT

Si lo que necesitas es la cootizacion de los activos argentinos, por QUANDL podras ver los que tienen ADR como GGAL, YPF, PAMP, etc, ya que esos mismos tickers cotizan en NYSE

Si lo que necesitas es el indice merval y las acciones argentinas en tiempo real, lamentablemente no hay ninguna herramienta gratuita, pero yo encontre al broker invertironline.com que si tenes cuenta con ellos te da acceso gratuito a su API REST que es bastante basica pero que te da acceso por CURL a datos de mercado argentino en tiempo real y no te cobran el uso de la API, pero tenes que tener cuenta con ellos

Answer (score 0):

Encontre esta API que al día de hoy funciona, tiene varias consultas básicas: https://api.estadisticasbcra.com/

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/403287)

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).